# What is system completion code 806 abend while running JCL?

Tags: jcl

While running the JCl am getting abend code 806 like completion code system =806 so please help me to solve it.
Thank you.

Comment: Suggest you try googling s806; you will find that the ZOS can not find the requested program

Comment: Google is your friend, as are the manuals.  MVS System Codes is where you should have started with this.

Answer (score 5):

If you new to the **IBM mainframe** (ZOS) and a job fails
I suggest you

- Look in the **Jobs output**, there will be a **message** (often IEC*) that list the error code and more details on the problem
- Look the message up in the **IBM manuals** (most sites using the Mainframe will have link to the IBM Manuals). The message description is generally accurate but some time hard to understand, you will get the hang of reading the manuals.
- Try **googling** both the Message and system codes.

In this case s806 means module not found. Remember it could a dynamically loaded module that is missing. Likely causes include

- misspelled program name
- incorrect or missing joblib/steplib

---

On stackoverflow you **need** to show you have made **some effort** before asking a question!!